# Draw resized SVG image in HTML canvas in Firefox

Tags: firefox, canvas, svg

I want to draw a resized SVG image to a HTML canvas.

It works fine in Chromium, but not in Firefox. In Firefox, the image is pixelated.

Here is the SVG image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200" height="200" viewbox="0 0 200 200">
  <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

And here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Resized SVG in Canvas</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>

        <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
                context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
                image = new Image();
            image.src = 'circle1.svg';
            image.height = 400;
            image.width = 400;

            image.addEventListener('load', function() {
                try {
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 400, 400);
                }
                catch(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }, false);
        }, false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas height="600" id="canvas" width="600"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

The result is:

[image]

I would like to have the resized SVG image drawn without pixelation in Firefox, as in Chromium.

Currently, I put `<img/>` on top on the canvas to get SVG image without pixelation, but it is quite slow because there are a lot of images.

Comment: Have you considered just drawing the circle(s) using the native canvas api:  context.arc(x,y,radius,0,Math.PI*2,false)?  Many of the SVG primitive shapes are also available in canvas--even paths are reasonably easy to convert.

Comment: It is only an example. I want to draw more complex SVG images.

Comment: This a great question that shows that Firefox's Gecko rendering engine converts the SVG to a bitmap immediately, whereas Webkit keeps it as SVG and renders it directly when needed.  That explains why my 20000 unit wide SVG couldn't be rendered in Firefox even when drawn 400 pixels wide.  It ran fine on webkit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a way of drawing a resized SVG on a canvas in Firefox. The idea is to get the SVG source via AJAX and change the SVG via JavaScript with something like:

```
var transformTag;

transformTag = $(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g'))
    .attr('transform', 'scale(' + scaleX + ', ' + scaleY + ')');

svgElement.attr({
    'height': dh,
    'viewbox': '0 0 ' + dw + ' ' + dh,
    'width': dw
})
    .wrapInner(transformTag);
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yAryg/) (without AJAX but it is simple to change).

Since the modification and image creation is slow, I added a simple cache mechanism (not shown in the fiddle, but once again, it is easy to implement) and the speed is really fast.

It works in Chromium, Firefox and Opera (but for some reason, the fiddle does not work in Opera, though it works in my development server).

P.S.: if there is a jQuery alternative to `document.createElementNS`, I would like to know.

Comment: Here's a first pass at a jQuery-free version, just in case anyone's looking for it: https://jsfiddle.net/82auztsy/